# Pyqt5 qlabel update while button is running

Tags: python, pyqt5

When the button is pressed, I want the pictures in the selected folder path to be displayed at 1 second intervals. But the interface is not updated until the method I connected the button to finishes. What can I do?

```
    def analyze_button_clicked(self):

    for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(self.input_output_tree.topLevelItem(0).text(0)):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".jpeg"):
                image_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                pixmap = QPixmap(image_path)
                self.process_image.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you to implement the Signals & Slots mechanism to manage what you want to accomplish, since what you want to do needs to manage some sort of syncronicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will likely update if you call `QApplication.processEvents()` after updating the Pixmap, like so:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def analyze_button_clicked(self):
    for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(self.input_output_tree.topLevelItem(0).text(0)):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".jpeg"):
                image_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                pixmap = QPixmap(image_path)
                self.process_image.setPixmap(pixmap)
                QApplication.processEvents()
```

However, like Cristian said, it is advisable to use [Signals & Slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)